# Change of basis question with linear mapping

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

for Question 2 d) can someone point out where my working went wrong:

[image: exercise2]

Here is my working:

every vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ after applying basis $B$ is: $\begin{align}      \begin{bmatrix}            x_{1}+x_3 \\                        x_1+x_{2} \\                       x_{1}+x_3          \end{bmatrix}   \end{align}$. Obtained by applying $ \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} 1&0&1\\ 1&1&0\\ 0&1&1 \end{array}\right]$ to $\begin{align}      \begin{bmatrix}            x_{1}\\                        x_{2} \\                       x_3          \end{bmatrix}   \end{align}$.

Similarly, every vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$ after applying basis $A$ is: $\begin{align}      \begin{bmatrix}            2x_{1}-x_2+x_3 \\                       -x_2+x_3         \end{bmatrix}   \end{align}$.

So, ${}_A[f]_B = \begin{align}      \begin{bmatrix}            2&0&-1\\                       2&-2&1         \end{bmatrix}   \end{align}$ by $ \begin{align}      \begin{bmatrix}            2&0&-1\\                       2&-2&1         \end{bmatrix}    \begin{bmatrix}            x_{1}+x_3 \\                        x_1+x_{2} \\                       x_{1}+x_3          \end{bmatrix}   = \begin{bmatrix}            2x_{1}-x_2+x_3 \\                       -x_2+x_3         \end{bmatrix} \end{align} $.

the correct answer is : ${}_A[f]_B = \begin{align}      \begin{bmatrix}            \frac{1}{2}&0&\frac{3}{2}\\  -\frac{1}{2}&1&\frac{3}{2}         \end{bmatrix}   \end{align}$